# New window in PySimpleGUI not closing itself

Tags: python, pysimplegui

So I have a Python script 'main' which creates a PySimpleGUI window. Using an event in the main window, I call a function from another Python script which makes another PySimpleGUI. This new window is supposed to take values from the user and when 'Submit' is selected, it is supposed to make changes and close itself. The function works well on its own, but when called by 'main', it does not close itself on clicking Submit.

'main' page code:

```
elif event == 'New':
       window.disable()
       n = New()
       window.enable()
       refresh(Ref)
```

Second page code:

```
from DBmethods import Newentry
import PySimpleGUI as sg
def New():
    layout=[[sg.Text('Enter Details of New Deal: \t', font='Arial 15', justification='center')],
            [sg.Text('Enter Name: \t\t'), sg.Input(key='Name')],
            [sg.Text('Enter Opportunity: \t\t'), sg.Input(key='Opportunity')],
            [sg.Text('Enter Value: \t\t'), sg.Input(key='Value')],
            [sg.Text('Choose Start Date:\t\t'),sg.Input(key='Startdate'),sg.CalendarButton('Open Calendar', target='Startdate',format='%d/%m/%Y')],
            [sg.Text('Choose Closing Date:\t'),sg.Input(key='Closedate'),sg.CalendarButton('Open Calendar', target='Closedate',format='%d/%m/%Y')],
            [sg.Text('Value must be a number', text_color='red',visible=False, key='errorv')],
            [sg.Text('You must fill all fields', text_color='red',visible=False, key='error')],
            [sg.Button('Save New Entry',key='Save')]
            ]
    window = sg.Window('New Entry', layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break

        elif event=='Save':
            if values['Name']=='' or values['Opportunity']=='' or values['Value']=='' or values['Startdate']=='' or values['Closedate']=='':
                window['error'].Update(visible=True)
            elif not values['Value'].isnumeric():
                window['errorv'].Update(visible=True)
            else:
                window['error'].Update(visible=False)
                window['errorv'].Update(visible=False)
                Newentry(values['Name'],values['Opportunity'],int(values['Value']),values['Startdate'],values['Closedate'])
                break
```

What must I do so that this works as intended on the 'main' page?

Comment: Remember to always call `window.close()` statement to close the window, not depend on end of script.